# Compare two columns if value exists in both CSV files

Tags: bash, csv, awk

The goal is to collect file names to be copied to target FileSystem (using AWK):

1. if they are in source.csv and does not exists in target.csv
2. file size is different
3. timestamp is grater in source than in target

Source.csv

```
"2023-08-25","test/test2/filename1","10.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename2","15.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename3","5.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename4","5.00 B"
```

Target.csv

```
"2023-08-25","test/test2/filename0","10.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename2","10.00 B"
"2023-07-24","test/test2/filename3","5.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename4","5.00 B"
```

Expected output:

```
"2023-08-25","test/test2/filename1","10.00 B"  ### Because does not exists in target.csv
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename2","10.00 B"  ### Because the size is different
"2023-07-24","test/test2/filename3","5.00 B"   ### Because the timestamp in source.csv is grater than in target.csv (meaning new version in source, not in target)
```

For the unique files I used:

`awk -v FS="," 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } FNR == NR { unique[$2]; next } !($2 in unique) { print $2 }' target.csv source.csv | tr -d "\"" > files_to_copy.txt`

But for other two conditions I am not able to develop the code. Missing AWK knowledge. Any help ? :)

Comment: you don't go into much detail about your ultimate goals here - but are you sure you aren't reinventing `rsync`?

Comment: Can filenames contain commas? (eg. `"test/test2/file,name"`) What about double-quotes? (eg. `"test/test2/file""name"`)

Comment: Looks very "pedagogical" to me. Those size, and time stamp with dates only... So the exercise is to rewrite rsync with awk. That's ok. See [how to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). But we need to know it to answer. Otherwise, it is hard for us to guess, for example, that it is ok to reinvent rsync. Or that the goal is not really to implement a full CSV parser, able to treat differently comma that are between quotes and those that separates fields, etc.

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about but don't pipe the awk output to `tr`, just change `print $2` to `gsub(/"/,""); print $2`

Comment: what if a filename appears multiple times in a file with different values for time or size ?

Comment: when you talk about 'file names' do you also take into consideration the directory name? for example, if `source.csv` contains the file named `test/test2/file1` and `target.csv` contains the file named `dir/dir2/file1` ... are these considered the same (because of the common `file1`) or are these considered different (because of the different directory names)?

Comment: will all sizes include the same unit of measurement of `B`? or could there be other units of measurement (eg, `KB`, `MB`, etc)? if there could be something other than `B` then please update the question to show an example as well as explain how to process; of interest would be something like `1 KB` and `1024 B` ... would these be considered as 'equal'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all fields are wrapped in a pair of double quotes
- there are no embedded/escaped double quotes in the data fields
- filenames are unique within a file (ie, a filename will not show up more than once in a file)
- all sizes have a unit of measurement of `B`
- the first non-blank character in the size field is a number

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'"' '                          # input field separator is double quote => data values are in even-numbered fields
FNR==NR { unique[$4]                 # use filename index for arrays
          size[$4]=$6+0              # "+0" will strip spaces and trailing "B", leaving us with just a number
          date[$4]=$2
          next
        }
!( $4 in unique       ) ||           #      if source file not in unique[] array then print current line
 ( size[$4] != ($6+0) ) ||           # (or) if sizes are different then print current line
 ( $2 > date[$4]      )              # (or) if source date is greater than target date then print current line
' target.csv source.csv
```

This generates:

```
"2023-08-25","test/test2/filename1","10.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename2","15.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename3","5.00 B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk regardless of which characters (except newline) appear in the file names in the CSV, and assuming each file name is unique:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    name = $0
    gsub(/^"[^"]*|[^"]*"$/,"",name)
}
NR == FNR {
    d[name] = $1
    s[name] = $NF
    next
}
!(name in d) || ($1 > d[name]) || ($NF != s[name])
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Target.csv Source.csv
"2023-08-25","test/test2/filename1","10.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename2","15.00 B"
"2023-07-25","test/test2/filename3","5.00 B"
```

The above assumes there won't be any commas or double quotes in the first or last fields of the CSVs.